# How to install Cobertura in azure Devops?

Tags: unit-testing, docker, code-coverage, azure-pipelines, cobertura

I have a .net core whith CI in Azure devops.

After successfully running my unit tests, I would like to generate and display code coverage using ReportGenerator, based on this article:

https://www.meziantou.net/computing-code-coverage-for-a-dotnet-core-project-with-azure-devops-and-coverlet.htm

Part of the YAML:

```
- script: |
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**Tests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura
 displayName: Create Code coverage report
```

This gives me the folling error:

```
...line 2: Cobertura: command not found
```

By removing the Cobertura from reporttypes, there are no errors, but then there are no report to be shown.

How can I install or enable Cobertura?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By removing HtmlInline_AzurePipelines from reporttypes, it worked

Answer (score 3):

This way you are skipping a parameter option. Accordingly to the documentation, you can try to wrap that option with `"` like in the following:

```
    - script: |
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**Tests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage "-reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura"
 displayName: Create Code coverage report
```

This should probably work as well without skipping it.